# Distribution with two (or more) medians

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, examples-counterexamples, median

Is there any example with a distribution with two or more medians? I was reading about the median on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median and here it says that there may be more than one median, but I haven´t been able to give such an example. I would really appreciate if you can help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let random variable $X$ take on values $0$ and $1$, each with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Then any $b$ with $0\lt b\lt 1$ is a median of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't say there may be more than one median value for the distribution.

It says there may be more than one *sample* value that is the median.

Thus if our sample is $\{2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2\}$, $2$ is the median, and there are more than one of them in the sample.

Comment: I do not think this is what the wikipedia entry is talking about. The sentence on multiple medians is in the section entitled 'Probability Distributions' so is not referring to the sample median.